# How do I read numbers from a file and assign them to multiple arrays? - C

Tags: c, arrays, file, numbers

I have to create a program that reads a file with numbers set up like this

```
3 1     4 3     2 5
1 4     etc.
```

and set them up into multiple arrays so 3 and 1 need to be in the same space in two different arrays, but in the same slot. So both 3 and 1 should end up in slot 1, 1, 4 3 would be in slot 1, 2, and so on.

I'm trying to find some form of tutorial, but so far no luck. I'm using a structure with two integers to try to assign the each number to their respective integers but can't get it to read them as explained.

If anyone knows what I'm looking for and can tell me the actual term for it so I can have a better chance to find something or can point me to a tutorial so I can properly understand how to do it I would be very grateful.

Update: Okay so far still not getting it to work, the simplest way I can describe what I want to do, is I want to read the first number, skip the second, read the third, skip the fourth, etc. and then I’ll create a separate scan statement to read the skipped numbers.

Comment: If you're having issues with a piece of code, show the code so we can see where you might be going wrong.

Comment: Are you having problems reading from the file, saving on the array or both?

Comment: You are looking for "File IO" and "Arrays".

Comment: We aren't supposed to post the code, it's for a class, and I'd prefer to learn how to do it myself. We were taught how to do something similar, but with manual entries into the program, not from a file.

Comment: Thank you Eugene Sh. I think I already found something.

Comment: Where is your code attempt?

Comment: If you have found something then please share it here with everyone.

Comment: Thought I did didn’t help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. What I was doing wrong was I created a scanf to scan each

```
      fscanf(ifp, “%d” &thing[i][j].1);
      fscanf(ifp, “%d” &thing[i][j].2);
```

When I should have done

```
      fscanf(ifp, “%d%d” &thing[i][j].1, &thing[i][j].2);
```